# tabTextAppearance attribute doesn't accept hex color code?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.yazan.mylanguage.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        style="@style/CategoryTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style for a tab that displays a category name -->
    <style name="CategoryTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Text appearance style for a category tab -->
    <style name="CategoryTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textColor">#A8A19E</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

when i try to put hex color code `#A8A19E` instead of `@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance` it doesn't work and give me an error,
 why this happen ? although this attribute accept color value ,
i need explain please !?

Comment: Because `tabTextAppearance` is a `style`, not a `color`. `textColor` is just one attribute of many possible in that `style`.

Comment: how you know tabTextAppearance is style not an a attribute where i can found this information??

Comment: You can put color in that style using `@color/your_color_name`.Hence the final code becomes -`<item name="tabTextAppearance">@color/your_color_name</item>`

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question. I just kinda "picked it up" along the way. Maybe someone else will know of some helpful references. Though, if you do a search for `TextAppearance`, you'll eventually end up at [the `R.style` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#TextAppearance).

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal there is no difference between @color/your_color_name and the hex color code true? so why accept this and refused the  hex color code ??

Comment: @MikeM.i need clear reference that can i understand clearly !! so we can put style as an attribute to another style!?

Comment: <item name="tabTextAppearance">#A8A19E</item> .Does this works for you

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal no it does not work i can't define item tag in resource and refer it , it's give me am error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your hex color code in the file and then refer to that color by `@color/color_name`.

If you define your color  in this `resource` file as-

```
`<item name="my_color" type="color">#A8A19E</item>`
```

Hence your final code in the `resource` file for text-appearance will be

```
` <!-- Text appearance style for a category tab -->
    <style name="CategoryTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
    </style>`
```

Comment: i need know why tabTextAppearance attribute doesn't accept hex color code like other attribute ?

Comment: Because TabTextAppearance always takes a reference to another resource .Refer this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabTextAppearance

Answer (score 0):

The `tabTextAppearance` attribute takes, as the name implies, a TextAppearance. It does not take a color directly. The code you have included for `styles.xml` -- where you are referecing a text appearance style -- is correct.

See the [styleable documentation for TextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextAppearance) for a list of valid attributes inside your text appearance style.

Comment: what do you mean by "name implies" can you explain this concept ??